# HOW is the Gallbladder attached to the liver

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, surgery

The gallbladder’s function is to store bile from the liver which is delivered through the cystic (bile) duct.  The cystic artery is also connected to the gallbladder to deliver blood.  (Correct me if I am wrong about any of this.)

However, when I was watching a gallbladder surgery [video on YouTube](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rPuYHj1IDKc), in the process of removing the gallbladder the surgeon clips the bile duct and artery which I understand but he/she also cauterises the gallbladder off the liver.  I also understand that The cauterisation is to prevent bleeding.

BUT the question is **WHY is the gallbladder attached to the liver in the first place?**  WHAT purpose does being attached to the liver serve? Does it provide stability? Because I always thought the gallbladder just sits beneath the liver.  Most importantly, **HOW is the gallbladder connected to the liver?**  (This maybe be more of a chemistry question), what bonds is it connect through, what/which biomolecule connects it and why is it that biomolecule/ bond that is used.

As watching the video,  I also noted that the surgeon didn’t clip the cystic vein, or even mentioned it.  Maybe I am wrong and he/she did clip the cystic vein but I didn’t see, would you also be kind enough to explain to me why the surgeon didn’t clip the cystic vein or if he did why it wasn’t pointed out.  Also tell me more about the cystic vein where is it located because it’s very hard to find clear diagrams with them...(is it because it’s small)

Comment: Hi welcome to Bio.SE! Posts should not contain multiple questions. Please remove the final paragraph of your post as it has nothign to do with the main question. You may opt to post it as a secondary question in a separate post.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Gallbladder attachement to the liver**

In **[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fsp9Rk0laVA)** (check from 55 sec on), you can see that the gallbladder is covered by a thin sheath that wraps the gallbladder; the sheath extends to the liver and intestine and thus keeps the gallbladder in place. The sheath is a part of the abdominal membrane (peritoneum) that covers most of the abdominal organs. You can see that the surgeon is cutting the sheath.

**2. [The Cystic Vein: The Significance of a Forgotten Anatomic Landmark (PubMed Central)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3016730/)**

> ...**there is no cystic vein per se,** but the venous drainage is
>   through the bed of the liver [between the attachment surfaces of the
>   gallbladder and liver]...however..Gray's
>   Anatomy of the Human Body...describes cystic veins which join at the
>   neck of the gallbladder to form either single or double cystic veins
>   which flow **along the cystic duct** and upward along the hepatic
>   ducts.

Comment: there are also accessory ducts (Luschka) that can connect to the gall bladder directly. Not all bile enters the gall bladder through the common bile duct. These additional ducts need to be sealed to prevent bile being leaked directly into the body cavity.

Comment: @John, that's a valuable info.